# How to check if file is completely written / holds a write lock with only read access in Java

Tags: java

I have a process writing a file to the system. Now I want to check in Java if the file is fully written (i.e. no write lock exists). However, I only have read access to this file!

As far as I understand it is not possible to try an exclusive lock, because I only have read permissions. I also don't want to sleep the Thread and check for changes of the file size because this is too slow. I cannot change anything about the process writing the file. The file has to remain in-place.

Any viable idea?

Comment: An alternative is to have that other process write the file to a temporary location and atomically move it to the final destination after writing is complete. "With an ATOMIC_MOVE you can move a file into a directory and be guaranteed that any process watching the directory accesses a complete file."  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/move.html